# Select "All" with AMP setState

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to implement select all functionality using `amp-selector`. My Code:

```
  <style amp-custom="">
 
    .hidden,
    .regionOptions p {
      display: none;
    }
    .regionOptions p.visible {
      display: block;
    }

  </style>  

  <amp-state id="selected">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "US": false,
        "Europe": false,
        "Asia": false    
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>

  <amp-selector id="regions" on="select:AMP.setState({selected: {region: event.targetOption}})">
        <option option="US" value="US">US</option>
        <option option="Europe" value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option option="Asia" value="Asia">Asia</option>
  </amp-selector>

  <div class="regionOptions">
    <p [class]="selected.region == 'US' ? 'visible' : ''" class="visible">US</p>
    <p [class]="selected.region == 'US' ? 'visible' : ''" class="visible">US</p>
    <p [class]="selected.region == 'Europe' ? 'visible' : ''" class="visible">Europe</p>
    <p [class]="selected.region == 'Europe' ? 'visible' : ''" class="visible">Europe</p>
    <p [class]="selected.region == 'Asia' ? 'visible' : ''" class="visible">Asia</p>
  </div>
```

Basically my goal is to add another option to `amp-selector` e.g.: `<option>All</option>` which will be selected on page load and all elements in `.regionOptions` visible. I've tried to implement that using `event.selectedOptions` instead of `event.targetOption`, because it can  contain an array of the `option` attributes, and have 'All' option to be something like this: `<option option="US, Europe, Asia">All</option>` but it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: what happens if you only do "All" - removing individual selectors?

Comment: @Jay Gray didn't get that, can u provide a sample please?